# error while changing the ui namespace to lightning namespace

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, controller

I have a requirement to change the namespaces from **ui:** to **lightning:** as ui namespaces are going to get depricated in May'21.
While doing so, I'm getting the error from the following tag

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://ui:inputDate" />
```

To change the namepsace from ui:inputDate to lightning:input for date, I need to provide type = "date". But in the above tag, I'm getting error while doing so. Below is the line

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://lightning:input" type="date" />
```

Below is the error i'm getting

> Failed to save CustomLightningComponent.cmp: Invalid type: date:
> Source

Also, I'm having this namespace in helper.js as well.

```
return this.createComponent('ui:inputDate', opts);
```

Can anyone please suggest on how to update ui:inputdate to lightning:input with type as date in the above component and helper.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type attribute is the type of resource that the component depends on. The default value is COMPONENT.

> The most commonly used values are:
>
> 1. COMPONENT
> 2. EVENT
> 3. INTERFACE
> 4. APPLICATION
>
> Use a comma-separated list for multiple types; for example: COMPONENT,
> APPLICATION.

The type, `date` you need to pass into the **attributes** of the component which is `opt` in your case.

```
$A.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, function callback)
```

[aura:dependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_dependency.htm) | [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

Comment: that means, if i just provide lightning:input instead of ui:inputdate is sufficient without type = "date" tag?
I'm having a doubt that how the component understands the tag as date tag without type?

Comment: yes in dependency you don't need to provide the type of input. You mention that in the call to `createComponent`(second link from the answer.)