# Assertion Failed error when namespace is changed in aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller

Similar to [this Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316335/error-while-changing-the-ui-namespace-to-lightning-namespace/316337#316337), when i change the namespace in aura component from **ui:inputText** to **lightning:input**, I'm getting the following error:

> Assertion Failed!: Attribute not defined in the component : false

Below is the code:

Component:

```
 <lightning:input type = "text" click="{!c.onfocus}" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.keyPressController}"  value="{!v.SearchKeyWord}" placeholder="search.." disabled="{!v.disable}"/>
```

Controller.js:

```
onfocus : function(component,event,helper){
        var forOpen = component.find("searchRes");
            $A.util.addClass(forOpen, 'slds-is-open');
            $A.util.removeClass(forOpen, 'slds-is-close');
         var getInputkeyWord = '';
         helper.searchHelper(component,event,getInputkeyWord);
    },
    
keyPressController : function(component, event, helper) {
        var getInputkeyWord = component.get("v.SearchKeyWord");
        if( getInputkeyWord.length > 0 ){
             var forOpen = component.find("searchRes");
               $A.util.addClass(forOpen, 'slds-is-open');
               $A.util.removeClass(forOpen, 'slds-is-close');
            helper.searchHelper(component,event,getInputkeyWord);
        }
        else{  
             component.set("v.listOfSearchRecords", null ); 
             var forclose = component.find("searchRes");
               $A.util.addClass(forclose, 'slds-is-close');
               $A.util.removeClass(forclose, 'slds-is-open');
          }
         
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know if i missed anything in the above component and controller so that i can get this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the attributes for lightning:input are different from ui:inputText

[ui:inputText attribute specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputText/specification)

[lightning:input attribute specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification)

The following attributes from your markup for lightning:input is not supported:
**click**,
**updateOn**
and **keyup**.
This is why it is throwing an error.

There are different attributes for handling these changes like:
**onchange**,
**onblur** and
**onfocus**

**Edit**:
Also, the 3 attributes mentioned are not a replacement for the old, they have different implementations. please check the documentation. Each expects a controller action like {!c.}

Comment: now when i change click, updateon and keyup with onchange, onblur and onfocus, I am getting the error as "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.". The error is not traced in the debug log as well. Please suggest

Comment: can you share the updated markup code?

Comment: please find the code here:

<lightning:input type = "text" onchange="{!c.onfocus}" onblur ="keyup" onfocus="{!c.keyPressController}"  value="{!v.SearchKeyWord}" placeholder="search.." disabled="{!v.disable}"/>

Comment: Also, the 3 attributes mentioned are not a replacement for the old, they have different implementations. please check the documentation. Each expects a  controller action like {!c.}

Comment: Yes. so, in this case, onBlur="keyUp" is not required.
OnBlur, Onfocus, and OnChange are 3 different events, each expecting a controller function.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and it worked:)

Do you have any idea about the lightning namespace alternative for ui:scrollwrapper?

Comment: I found something in slds, but I'm not sure if this is a replacement for ui:scrollerWrapper 
you need to add the class 'slds-scrollable'
<div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:5rem;width:24rem">
</div>
reference: https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/#site-main-content